# Unable to allow external customers in chatter groups

Tags: chatter, customer-community, public-group, chatter-groups

I am trying to create groups in Salesforce and allow external customers to join them in order to discuss details about cases and maintain privacy by creating a group for each customer.

- The organization has the Chatter External License which has available licenses.
- In Chatter Settings, I have enabled the option to "Allow Customer Invitations".
- The organization also has the Chatter Free license with available licenses.
- Whenever I create a group, I enter the details and then change the privacy to private, there is no chcekbox to "Allow customers"
- If I do the same procedure to create an unlisted group, again there is no option to "Allow Customers".
- This is the Sandbox instance that I am talking about, does that have something to do with it?

Note: We know how to use the Chatter integration internally but that is not our purpose. Our purpose is to use it to communicate with customers and have processes deployed around it (such as email alerts to the customer when we create a comment and vice versa, change status of the case when a comment is added etc.)

Side Note: While doing a trailhead in a playground, I was able to create a private group and here it had the option to "Allow Customers", so that rules out the suspicion that the option may have been deprecated.

Any help is appeciated.

Comment: I am facing this issue too, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

What Salesforce UI are you using? What edition is your org? When was the sandbox instance setup?

*There isn't a setting to prevent "Allow Customers" I find it odd that in your sandbox org its greyed out when you try to create a Private Group.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to Classic interface. That option is in the Classic interface.